# Bluetooth Latency compensation on Android

Tags: java, android

I'm wanting to develop an app for my personal use so that several mobile devices can pair to several Bluetooth speakers (regardless of the brand).
Because the sync will take place through internet, and that the app may become cross-platform overtime, it is essential that I can give to the device which is synced to me the ability to manually tweak its Bluetooth latency (ms offset), so that the speakers can be in phase. That was achieved previously because I saw it in certain apps; yet I can't find any developer information about it!
Any ideas as to how one would go about developing it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think compensating for Android Bluetooth Latency using app side code only is possible, because the latency varies a lot by manufacturer.

It might be possible though if you can modify your speaker firmwares in order to add timestamp based syncing between your speakers... or use Wi-Fi speakers

For more developer information about Android Bluetooth Latency, read this:

https://www.soundguys.com/android-bluetooth-latency-22732/

Comment: Indeed, I am referring to a manual offset setting. I have seen it done to this exact purpose on another app so it must be possible!